# Método para saber si dos intervalos de fecha se solapan

Tags: java, date

¿Existe alguna manera en Java de que, declarando dos intervalos de tiempo con `fechaInicio` y `fechaFin`, compararlos y saber si se solapan o no?

Comment: Pedro, bienvenido. Que has intentado hasta ahora? Muestranos un poco de codigo.

Comment: E estudiado un poco de javascript en la parte de sus metodos como intervalos y me gustaria conocer a que te refieres con solapan ?, quizas conociendo tu problema me lleguen ideas locas que te puedan ayudar asolventar la problematica como tambien poner en practica mis conocimientos para crecer como desarrollador y poder ser un tutor mas adelante en busca de ayudar a quien lo necesitan

Comment: El termino solapar me confunde. Que quieres decir exactamente?

Comment: Quiere decir que el intersecto no sea vacio, es decir, el intervalo A: 7/15/2017 a 7/19/2017 se solapa con el intervalo B: 7/17/2017 a 7/25/2017, ya que las fechas 7/17/2017 a 7/19/2017 estarian en ambos intervalos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En java, existe una librería para trabajar solo con fechas, se llama [Joda](http://joda.org/joda-time/)

Incluye una clase de `Interval` que tiene un método`overlaps`(solapan):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

DateTime fechaInicio1 = formatter.parseDateTime("02/10/2017");
DateTime fechaFin1 = formatter.parseDateTime("05/10/2017");

DateTime fechaInicio2 = formatter.parseDateTime("03/10/2017");
DateTime fechaFin2 = formatter.parseDateTime("08/10/2017");

Interval intervalo1 = new Interval( fechaInicio1, fechaFin1 );
Interval intervalo2 = new Interval( fechaInicio2, fechaFin2 );

System.out.println( intervalo1.overlaps( intervalo2 ) ); 
// imprime true porque si se sobreponen.
```

> A partir de java 8, Java implementa [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) el cual implementa muchas de las funcionalidades de joda, sin embargo, no soporta `Interval`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el tiempo en milisegundos con `getTime()`:

```
Date date = new Date().getTime();
```

Haces esto para tus fechas y comparas, si el tiempo de la fecha fin del primer intervalo es mayor que el de la fecha de inicio del segundo intervalo es que solapan.

Comment: También deberias tener en cuenta si el tiempo de la fecha fin del segundo intervalo es mayor que el de la fecha de inicio del primer intervalo, nada garantiza que los intervalos estén ordenados cronológicamente. Además a nivel de cada intervalo deberías ordenar fecha inicio y fin para que esta comparación sea coherente.

Comment: Todo es posible, mientras no haya código la respuesta es amplia como la pregunta, aunque yo creo que es más sencillo ordenar primero los intervalos a comparar y hacer luego la comparación.

Answer (score 0):

Cree una clase que te retorna las fechas solapadas como tipo Calendar entre 2 pares de fechas:

```
 public class RangoFecha implements Iterable<Calendar>
    {
    private final Date inicio;
    private final Date _final;

    /**
     *
     * @param _inicio
     * @param _final
     */
    public RangoFecha(Date _inicio, Date _final)
    {
        this.inicio = _inicio;
        this._final = _final;
    }

    public Date obtenerFechaInicial()
    {
        return this.inicio;
    }

    public Date obtenerFechaFinal()
    {
        return _final;
    }   

    public boolean esRangoSolapado(RangoFecha rango)
    {
        for(Calendar c : this)
        {
            for(Calendar c2 : rango)
            {
                boolean solapada = c.getTimeInMillis() == c2.getTimeInMillis();

                if(solapada)
                {
                   return true;
                }

            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    public ArrayList<Calendar> obtenerFechasSolapadas(RangoFecha rango)
    {
        ArrayList<Calendar> fechasSolapadas = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Calendar c : this)
        {
            for(Calendar c2 : rango)
            {
                boolean solapada = c.getTimeInMillis() == c2.getTimeInMillis();

                if(solapada)
                {
                   fechasSolapadas.add(c2);
                }

            }
        }

    return fechasSolapadas;
    }

    /**
     * Enumera el rango de fecha returnando todas las fechas
     * con la diferencia de un dia hasta la fecha final
     * y retorna la enumeracion en tipo Calendar
     */
    public ArrayList<Calendar> enumerarRango()
    {
        ArrayList<Calendar> rango = new ArrayList<>();

        Calendar cActual = dateToCalendar(this.inicio);
        Calendar cfinal = dateToCalendar(_final);

        rango.add((Calendar) cActual.clone());

        // agregamos la primera fecha
        boolean isMenorAfechaFinal;
        while( isMenorAfechaFinal = (cActual.getTimeInMillis() < cfinal.getTimeInMillis()) )
        {
            cActual.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            rango.add((Calendar)cActual.clone());
        }


         return rango;
    }

    private Calendar dateToCalendar(Date date)
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Calendar> iterator() {
       return  this.enumerarRango().iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return format.format(this.inicio) + " - " + format.format(_final);
    }


 }
```

La clase recibe un rango de fecha inicio-final de tipo Date(deberia de ser Calendar pero como fue date lo que se pidio en la OP).

El metodo `enumerarRango()` crea una lista de objectos calendar con todas las fechas del rango dado. Por ejemplo si le pasamos la fecha 1/julio/217 - 5/julio/2017, la enumeracion de la fecha seria un a lista con los siguientes elementos:

```
[0]- 1/julio/2017
[1]- 2/julio/2017
[2]- 3/julio/2017
[3]- 4/julio/2017
[4]- 5/julio/2017
```

El metodo `obtenerFechasSolapadas(RangoFecha rango)` retorna las fechas solapadas por medio a la enumeración de las fechas de cada rango. Lo que hace es que compara cada elemento de la enumeracion con el RangoFecha dado y verifica cuales elementos son iguales por el metodo `getTimeInMillis()`.

El metodo `esRangoSolapado()` indica si las los RangoFechas son solapadas.

Aqui un ejemplo de uso:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La clase no esta optimizada y no se toman en cuenta las diferencias de zonas horarias.**